# WIFI not working on hp15 ab522tx machine

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers

I am using `HP 15ab522tx` ,after installing **Ubuntu** `16.04` ,I am not able to fix WIFI issue.Also I tried various answers to this problem.But nothing seem to work for me.Installing **BROADCOM** driver did not work for me..Please help.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

gives:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 M.2 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel modules: wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

List of Wireless Drivers in windows 10 version:

- Broadcom Wireless LAN Driver
- Intel Wireless LAN Drivers
- Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Drivers

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS. Run `sudo modprobe wl` to check.

Answer (score -1):

You can try changing to a newer kernel. Either by manually downloading and installing the .deb files or by using a [gui tool](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html).

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12/

Download depending upon your OS type i.e (64-bit/amd64 or 32-bit/i386):

```
linux-headers-4.12.0-xxxxxx_all.deb
linux-headers-4.12.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
linux-image-4.12.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
```

Install by the following command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This will install the latest kernel files. Restart ubuntu for changes to take effect.